# same id for different elements strangely worked in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, components

It's known you can't use the same Id for different elements in HTML , like that for example :

```
import img1 from './images/img1.png'
import img2 from './images/img2.png'
export const Main =()=>{
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={img1} id="image"/> 
      <img src={img2} id ="image"/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

will raise error , but when I use React components to render the image element it works without error :

```
exort const Image =(props)=>{
    return (
      <img src={props.src} id="image"/>
    )
}
import img1 from './images/img1.png'
import img2 from './images/img2.png'
import Image from './image'
const Main =()=>{
    return (
      <div>
        <Image src={img1} />
        <Image src={img2}/>
      </div>
    )
}
```

any explanations  please ?

Comment: ID is supposed to be unique and only for one element per page. If you need to share an ID, use a class (css) instead.

Comment: _"will raise error"_ - No, it won't throw an error. Ids _should_ be unique but nothing stops you from using the same id more than once.

Comment: So, your question is why react doesn't "catch" this issue?

Comment: @evolutionxbox , yeah ,I know that , I am just wondering how it is possible to use same Id in React without any problem

Comment: @Andreas ,Actually it does , but when I use React Components like I show above , It works and nothing happens

Comment: @vanowm ,I just want to know if there is some thing behind the scene I don't know ,like if every rendering differences from other or something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think react would raise an error for using the same id for multiple elements. It just gives a warning. On the high level, the page is rendered as HTML, so your code works without any errors.